# Pause an exe with batch file

Tags: batch-file, exe, wait

I don’t know if this is possible

But can I pause an exe and wait for a batch file to complete before resuming with the exe again?

Comment: Are you starting the batch file process from within the exe?

Comment: Nope I'm using AutoCAD Autolisp program to launch and execute the batch file and I want AutoCAD to pause so that the batch can finish a few things first before continuing

Answer (score 4):

I would look into the SysInternals tool "pssuspend".  You can just give it a process ID:

```
PsSuspend suspends or resumes processes on a local or remote NT system.

Usage: pssuspend [-r] [\\RemoteComputer [-u Username [-p Password]]] <process Id or name>
     -r    Resume.
     -u    Specifies optional user name for login to
           remote computer.
     -p    Specifies optional password for user name. If you omit this
           you will be prompted to enter a hidden password.
```

Go to http://www.sysinternals.com, look up "process utilities" and then "pssuspend".

In general, I would recommend getting familiar with the sysinternals tools; they are extremely useful.